# Split a string on every third space

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I split a string on every third space? I'm wondering if python has built-in syntax for this or if it can be done using a list comprehension.

```
"a bb c dd ee f" -> ["a bb c", "dd ee f"]
```

Comment: you could do matching `re.findall(r'\S+\s\S+\s\S+', "a bb c dd ee f")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
re.split(r'(.*?\s.*?\s.*?)\s', "a bb c dd ee f")
```

and in order to remove empty strings from the result:

```
[x for x in re.split(r'(.*?\s.*?\s.*?)\s', "a bb c dd ee f") if x]
```

Comment: You could also do `re.split(r'(.*?\s.*?\s.*?)\s', "a bb c dd ee f")[1:]`

Comment: @MattDMo true, but since this string is only an example, and in a *real* case there might be additional empty strings, I chose a more general approach (even if more verbose).

Answer (score 1):

As a more general way you can use a function :

```
>>> def spliter(s,spl,ind):
...    indx=[i for i,j in enumerate(s) if j==spl][ind-1]
...    return [s[:indx],s[indx+1:]]
... 
>>> s="a bb c dd ee f"
>>> spliter(s,' ',3)
['a bb c', 'dd ee f']
```